# Beginner question on PHP, is there alternative ways to display data from mySQL than for/foreach/while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a small application instead of downloading a source code and use it.

I will display data from the database in many different places in my page. For example, I will have to display the NAME somewhere, the ADDRESS somewhere else and at the end of the page the BIRTH.

The page will display the details of one person only, based on the ID given through a form. Below is the way I know on how to display the details of the person with ID 1.

```
$query="select * from student WHERE id='1'";
```

and in every place that will be a personal detail about the person with ID 1 this?

```
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($rt)){
echo "$nt[name]<br>";
}
```

and in another place

```
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($rt)){
echo "$nt[address]<br>";
}
```

and somewhere else

```
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($rt)){
echo "$nt[birth]<br>";
}
```

My question is if there is another way of displaying info, instead of what I posted (including for/foreach loops and one big while loop), to display the details? Something faster maybe, with less repetitive code ?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming `id` is a number, do not compare it to a string `'1'`. Just write `WHERE id = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're only fetching one row, you do not need a loop at all.

Only once, issue your query and assign the first row to a variable.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = 1 LIMT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Now at one part of your page, `echo $row['name'];`, somewhere else you can `echo $row['address']`, and at the end you can `echo $row['birth'];`.

Comment: Using LIMIT 1 makes it even quicker because it does not search for other id's equals to 1 ?

Comment: Yes, it tells the database it can stop looking after it's found 1 row.

Comment: Although hopefully, your `id` field is indexed, which makes it a moot point.

Comment: The `LIMIT` is more about limiting the size of the cursor. After the first fetch, the cursor will be closed. As @Sam mentions, hopefully `id` is a primary key, therefore only one (or zero) rows will ever be returned